# Sum of values by different groups (2 joined DBs)

Tags: sum

I’ m facing an issue getting the results for sum of values by specific group of data from 2 combined databases.
Both DBs contain same attribute called ProductID. First DB in includes column category and other DB contains attribute revenue.
I need to get sum of revenues for every category. I’ve already combined DB’s with inner_joint function and now I don’t know how to calculate the sum of revenues.

Thanks for help!